# Trying to create new custom HTML elements which perform action in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, element

I am trying to create my own custom HTML elements where a user can interact with the text within that element. For Example, I created an element  where anything between those tags will have a pointer as a mouse cursor and when double clicked, something happens. EG:

```
<objdc>Double click me!</objdc>
```

However, this is my code and it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ObjDblClk = $('objdc');
    ObjDblClk.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    ObjDblClk.dblclick(function(e) {
        var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
        var word = $.trim(range.toString());
        if(word != '') {
           //Do Something

        }
        range.collapse();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a **bad** idea, to say the least. Stick with valid HTML instead

Comment: Bad or good idea aside it is an interesting question. So... what exactly is not working (can you be more explicit)? I'm expecting the cursor pointer works fine... the do something fails?

Comment: And what is the use of this? It won't be interpreted by the browsers and if it is only for your script, then create variables, functions and objects instead of this fancy stuff. To identify tags, either use "id" or "data" attributes.

Comment: It's not going to work. The browser won't know what your custom element is. Use something like `<div id="objdc"></div>` and then use standard jQuery to access whatever is in it.

Comment: It actually will work. Is does not respect standards and it is wrong from that point of view. But it has no reason not to work (actually tested that right now). Html is basically an xml subset and any decent browser implementation will recognized custom elements unless doctype sais otherwise. As for the use of this... that's up to OP to tell us or not.

Comment: Back on topic... script works fine except range.collapse. It expects more arguments there. TypeError: Not enough arguments to Selection.collapse. You can find the definition here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapse.

Comment: For me, in Chrome, it doesn't do anything. It won't change the cursor and double click doesn't work. And I know "generally" this is a bad idea and that I should work with DOM elements, etc... But I am taking a swipe at creating my own mark up language and interpreter.

Comment: Also, just to let you know.. Even if I try and use an actual HTML element such as <h2> or <p>, it still wont work for me. Anyone get me a JS Fiddle where it will work?

Comment: @JoeyGilda Added fiddle in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is related with the fact you are not using the collapse method right. It expects a node as parameter and an offset.

So... to fix that exact behavior you posted you would need to do something like:

```
     ObjDblClk.dblclick(function(e) {
        var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
        var word = $.trim(range.toString());
        if(word != '') {
           //Do Something

        }
        range.collapse(ObjDblClk[0], 0);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

**BUT (and this is important):** That will do absolutely nothing for your custom selection (especially since is on double click witch affects selection). So you can just remove that line completely and try another solution.

**Also**: You should read the comments. The guys are right. Unless you are working on some reall strange inhouse thing there may be better aproaches.

Fiddle here (added an alert so you see the function is called - don't forget to select something before double clicking): https://jsfiddle.net/713ndkm0/1/

Answer (score -1):

To create a custom tag like that, you have to be aware of certain things:

1. Not all browsers will understand your custom tag as a DOM object. IE is a notable example.
2. Your new custom tag should have a hyphen in it, like `obj-dc` ([more info](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements)).
3. If you want to use it in IE, you have to declare it up-front, as:

   `document.createElement('obj-dc');`

[Here is a link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) to creating new HTML tags for Chrome, in the new way, and [here is a link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) for the older API. As you can see, even the same browser cannot operate with custom tags consistently.